# What is the correct way to deploy CraftCMS 3 with git? I keep getting permission issues

Tags: git, craftcms

The way I am deploying and updating my craft 3 site now is by pushing the changes in my git repo to a bare repo on the server, which has a post-receive hook that does this:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ubuntu/www git checkout -f
cd /home/ubuntu/www && composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
```

But I can't seem to get the permissions right. Git will overwrite file modes so that the webserver can't write to directories that it needs to.

Is there a different way I should deploy or a way to keep permissions from getting messed up?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into https://deployer.org for deploying craftcms over git, that's the way I do it, fixes all the permission issues. A deployer config could look like this:

```php
<?php
namespace Deployer;

require 'recipe/common.php';

// Project name
set('application', 'my_project');

// Project repository
set('repository', 'git@gitlab.com/website.git');

// [Optional] Allocate tty for git clone. Default value is false.
set('git_tty', true); 

// Shared files/dirs between deploys 
set('shared_files', ['.env','config/license.key']);
set('shared_dirs', ['web/uploads', 'storage/logs', 'storage/backups']);

// Writable dirs by web server 
set('writable_dirs', ['web/uploads', 'storage/runtime', 'storage/logs', 'storage/backups', 'storage/runtime', 'web/cpresources']);
set('allow_anonymous_stats', false);

// releases
set('keep_releases', 3);

// Hosts

host('staging')
    ->hostname('example.com')
    ->port(22)
    ->user('root')
    ->set('deploy_path', '/var/www/staging'); 

host('production')
    ->hostname('example.com')
    ->port(22)
    ->user('root')
    ->set('deploy_path', '/var/www/html');   


// Tasks

desc('Deploy your project');
task('deploy', [
    'deploy:info',
    'deploy:prepare',
    'deploy:lock',
    'deploy:release',
    'deploy:update_code',
    'deploy:shared',
    'deploy:writable',
    'deploy:vendors',
    'deploy:clear_paths',
    'deploy:symlink',
    'deploy:unlock',
    'cleanup',
    'success'
]);

after('deploy:failed', 'deploy:unlock');
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks helpful. What about the composer update after deploy? I don't see that anywhere in this recipe.

Comment: it uses the current composer.lock, so if you're looking at composer update, do it locally and deploy with the new lock-file

Comment: Sorry, I do understand that part but an install command has to be run after deploy. That's what I'm wondering about.

Comment: oh, yes, for the first install… you can either run the install command on the server in the first release or add it as a custom task (https://deployer.org/docs/tasks.html)… or even in the postinstall of composer (https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md)